# NDK Build Error,Make.exe no such file or directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am trying to build the project .i have added native support to it.i am getting the following error in cosole.please help me

"> **16:10:52 **** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project MainActivity ****
"E:\NDK\android-ndk64-r10b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r10b\ndk-build.cmd" clean 
make.exe: E:\NDK\android-ndk64-r10b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r10b\build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `E:\NDK\android-ndk64-r10b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r10b\build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.**